# Trouble with syntax of preselection in a cursor

Tags: arcpy, cursor, select

I am trying to determine the maximum values in a column [1] in relation to a column [2]. For this purpose I have written all occurring values of column [2] in a list and now I want to make a selection when creating the cursors for finding the maximum in column [1]. If I write the value manually into my script it works fine, but if I want to use the list for the selection, my script unfortunately aborts. I guess that my issue is the preselection by definition of the secound cursor. How can I do this?

My current code is

```
#creating a list ->"mast_value" with unique values of field [ID_1]
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inLAS[:-4] + '_POLE_POINTS.SHP','ID_1') as max_cursor:
    for row in max_cursor:
        mast_value = sorted({row[0] for row in max_cursor})

#iterate through the list to find highest value in field [pointz], but only in features which have the value of the element of the list "mast_value"
for mast in mast_value:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inLAS[:-4] + '_POLE_POINTS.SHP','POINT_Z'), ("\"ID_1\" = mast") as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            print str(max(row))
```

Comment: Can you add the error message?

Comment: You have faulty row processing logic in the top search.

Comment: Use summary statistics or read data into a pandas dataframe and groupby

Comment: What's the value of `inLAS` when the code that you've presented starts to run?

Comment: it is the original name of the LAZ-file with their extension, which I cut of.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with following code:

```
#creating a list ->"mast_value" with unique values of field [ID_1]
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inLAS[:-4] + '_POLE_POINTS.SHP','ID_1') as max_cursor:
    for row in max_cursor:
        mast_value = sorted({row[0] for row in max_cursor})

#iterate through the list to find highest value in field [pointz], but only in features which have the value of the element of the list "mast_value"
field = "ID_1"
for mast in mast_value:
    abfrage = field + " = " + str(mast)
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inLAS[:-4] + '_POLE_POINTS.SHP',('POINT_Z', 'FID'), where_clause=abfrage) as mast_cursor:
        for row1 in mast_cursor:
            print(str(max(mast_cursor)))
```

I'm pretty sure there is much more efficient code, but this code works fine for me.

Comment: The summary statistics tool would allow you to achieve the same result with a lot less code to maintain